# MySQL query is not using the index

Tags: php, mysql, performance, indexing, query-performance

I have below query:

```
SELECT bank_code, bank_name
FROM system_bank_info
WHERE company_id=1 AND country_id=103 AND status='ACTIVE'
GROUP BY bank_name
ORDER BY bank_name ASC
```

TABLE SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE `system_bank_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bank_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `bank_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `branch_code` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `branch_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
  `bank_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_district` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bank_address` text,
  `bank_contact` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_type` enum('INSTA_CREDIT') DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `bank_code` (`bank_code`),
  KEY `branch_code` (`branch_code`),
  KEY `company_id_country_id_status` (`company_id`,`country_id`,`status`),
  CONSTRAINT `system_bank_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `company` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `system_bank_info_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `system_country_list` (`country_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150398 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

EXPLAIN:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys                           | key        | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | system_bank_info | ref  | country_id,company_id_country_id_status | country_id | 4       | const | 59324 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+-----------------------------------------+------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see there is an index called `company_id_country_id_status`. But, query still uses `country_id` only. How can I make this query more efficient?

I also tried adding indexes `bank_code` and `bank_name`. But, same result!

Comment: If `country_id` and `company_id` are both `int` type, why are you passing them as strings in the query? Also, could you quantify the performance problem you're facing, and let us know how many rows there are for `company_id` 1 and `country_id` 103, and in the table overall?

Comment: There are `124294` rows with `company_id` 1 and `country_id` 103

Comment: If `company_id` is not a selective index (low cardinality) then MySQL won't use it because it's a waste and won't yield any performance. You said there's `124294` rows with `country_id = 1` - that means its cardinality is low and it's an useless index (it's just wasting space and can't help yield any performance). You can force MySQL to use it, but it's not going to make the query faster - quite the contrary.

Comment: @Mjh: I figured out something here. When I use `country_id` = 210. Then it's using this index: `company_id_country_id_status`. Bcoz 210 has less data then 103.

Comment: That just confirms what I said.. indexes are only useful when their selectivity is high. If you have an index that's not selective, MySQL will choose not to use it. Basically, you can't do anything there - leave it as is, it works fine.

Comment: What version are you running?  If available, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

Comment: If nearly all the table is matched by the `WHERE` clause, then the _fastest_ way would be to ignore all indexes and do a table scan.

Comment: @RickJames: That's the case for that particular `country_id` as it's working for all other countries.

Comment: Does you client choke when it gets 120K rows?  Or are most of then INACTIVE?

Comment: @RickJames: Sometimes query is getting slower because of this. And most of them are ACTIVE

Answer (score 0):

You can give hints to the optimizer so that it uses a specific index. `USE INDEX ()`

```
SELECT bank_code, bank_name
FROM system_bank_info USE INDEX (company_id_country_id_status)
WHERE company_id=1 AND country_id=103 AND status='ACTIVE'
```

Comment: I tried this as well. But, it's not improving query performance. Same execution time.

Comment: @RonakPatel What *is* the execution time? (Also, the fact that forcing use of the the index doesn't help shows the query optimiser is probably doing its job correctly -- it knew it wouldn't help, so it didn't bother using it.)